# Bakcbone validation issue

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to validate some simple input fields with Backbone:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
validate: function(attr, options){
    if(attr.age < 18){
        return 'too young';
    }
    if(attr.firstname === ''){
        return 'name required';
    }
},
urlRoot: '/users'
});
```

In the View I am passing {validate:true} and on user: invalid I console.log the error from the validate function inherited from the model.

```
var EditUser = Backbone.View.extend({
el:'.page',
render: function(options){
    var that = this;
    if(options.id){
        that.user = new User({id: options.id});
        that.user.fetch({
            success: function(user){
                var template = _.template($('#edit-user-template').html(), {user:user});
                that.$el.html(template);
            }
        });
    } else{
        var template = _.template($('#edit-user-template').html(), {user:null});
        this.$el.html(template);
    }
},
events: {
    'submit .edit-user-form': 'saveUser',
    'click .delete': 'deleteUser'
},
saveUser: function (ev){
    var userDeatils = $(ev.currentTarget).serializeObject();
    var user = new User({validate:true});
    user.on("invalid", function(model, error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
    user.save(userDeatils,{
        success: function(user){
            router.navigate('', {trigger:true});
        }
    })
    return false;
},
deleteUser: function(ev){
    this.user.destroy({
        success: function(){
            router.navigate('', {trigger:true});
        }
    });
    return false;
}
});
```

All I get in the console.log is the first error 'too young' but not the second 'name required'. I would like each single error returned to populate a span tag to be fadeIn next to each relative input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used the validate functionality but looking at the implementation you shouldn't `return` immediately if an assumption fails.

If I had this problem I would change the validate function to accumulate the errors into an array instead of returning them instantly:

```
validate: function(attr, options){
    var errors = []
    if(attr.age < 18){
        errors.push('too young');
    }
    if(attr.firstname === ''){
        errors.push('name required');
    }
    return errors;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have also came across this one just now: http://beletsky.net/2012/11/baby-steps-to-backbonejs-model.html